# How do I rename a single column in multiple dataframes to the name of the dataframe in which they reside in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, naming

I am currently trying to rename a single column in multiple dataframes to match the dataframe name in R.

I have seen some questions/solutions on the site that are similar to what I am attempting to do, but none appear to do this dynamically.  I have over 45 dataframes I need rename a column in, so manually typing in each individual name is doable, but time consuming.

```
Dataframe1 <- column
Dataframe2 <- column
Dataframe3 <- column


I want it to look like this:
Dataframe1 <- Dataframe1
Dataframe2 <- Dataframe2
Dataframe3 <- Dataframe3


The ultimate goal is to have a master dataframe with columns Dataframe1, Dataframe2, and Dataframe3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get all the datasets into a `list` and rename at once in the `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "Dataframe\\d+")), function(x) {
             names(x)[5] <- "newcol"
             x})
```

#### Update

If we are renaming the columns in different datasets with different names, then create a vector of columns names that corresponds to each 'Dataframe' column name

```
nm1 <- c("col5A", "col5B", "col5C", ..., "col5Z")
lst2 <- Map(function(x) {names(x)[5] <- y; x}, 
         mget(ls(pattern = "Dataframe\\d+")),
           nm1)
```

---

In the above code, we are renaming the 5th column to 'newcol'.

---

It can also be done using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(mget(ls(pattern = "Dataframe\\d+")), ~ .x %>%
            rename_at(5, ~ "newcol"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I have played around with this, but the issue is I need to rename the columns each a different name.  So I want the name of the column to now be the name of a dataframe.  In other words, df1 would have a column named df1, df2 would have a column named df2, and so on and so forth.  Is there a way to loop through the dataframe list, identify the dataframe name and rename a column within that dataframe the same name?